# How do I invoke my C++ binaries via the CGI interface?

Tags: php, c++, mysql, linux, apache

I'd like to convert a PHP solution to a C++ solution. Currently I have my server-side written in PHP - not too much code, under a thousand lines.  So I can rewrite it with no problem - I don't need to use hip-hop or similar automations.

The question is how do I install/configure the correct software to support C++ code on the server side. I do not know how to invoke binaries by the web server via CGI.

PHP is easy, install XAMPP or similar write the PHP and you are pretty much up and going.

However, I want to run C++.

Thanks

Comment: [okws](http://www.okws.org/doku.php?id=okws) may be an option if you really want to run a C++-based website.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. What do you mean by "how do I set it up?". Are you looking for a C++ compiler or don't you know how to invoke binaries by the webserver via the [CGI interface](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875)?

Comment: Linux, Apache, MySQL, Perl/PHP/Python

Comment: @Chris: We want good questions. You question didn't make any sense.

Comment: Even after the edits, this question (or at least the title) is unclear. Are you asking how to be able to use C++ on a server? Or are you asking how to convert PHP code into C++? If it's the former, then PHP shouldn't even be mentioned in the question.

Comment: This is a good question with a good answer.  There are likely lots of people who want to switch from PHP to C++ and don't know where to begin.  The answer by tdammer provides this point of reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three basic options:

- do the whole thing in C++, making your program a standalone web server (possibly proxying through apache to provide things like ssl, static media, authentication etc.)
- run C++ in a cgi-bin, through apache
- make a PHP wrapper that shells out to the C++ part (this is a nice option if the performance-critical part is small, as you can still use the comfort that PHP's garbage collection and string manipulation gives you)

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke your C++ binaries via the Common Gateway Interface which is specified in [RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875).

Each webserver that supports CGI (and it's quite common) can then invoke your binaries. In case you're using apache 3.1 for performance and stablility reasons, there's a section in the manual: [Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/cgi.html).

*Cgi and c++* code examples are easily to be located via an internet search, so [this is just one example](http://library.thinkquest.org/16728/content/cgi/cplusplus.html).

When you got this to work and got used to it, you can think about going a step ahead and migrate to [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/). It helps to reduce the costs of forking a process each time as CGI does. Another option is that you create your script in form of an *apache module* and directly serve from within httpd.